# C# WinForms, remove unused controls

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

I'm working on a C# project (.net 3.5, visual studio 2008) and have a quick question for yo all:

Is is possible to remove controls that are never used?

By that I mean, is it possible to remove controls that have been added to the form but haven't been referenced anywhere in the code base (outside of the designer)?

The WinForms stuff I'm looking at has tens of controls with generic names ("textBox1, button 4, etc) that are not used by the code base (or even seen by the user).

Most of the form has controls on top of controls (not my decision), and there's a lot of layering of panels and splitters. This has lead to a situation where there are controls hidden from view, which never get used or attached to any event handlers.

I'm worried that these extra controls are going to leave a big memory footprint, or lead to performance issues - I've already seen the form become laggy after a ~10 minutes of use.

Obviously, I don't want to jump into the designer file and start removing references to controls that aren't necessary. the code base is checked into source control, but there have been many, many, **MANY** commits since it was first checked in.

I was thinking iterating through the following pattern:

- Cut a panel
- Paste it into a new (empty) project
- Remove any controls that I know are not used in the main project (anything with a generic name)
- Paste the panel back into the main project and re-build (to check for errors)

Are there any (potentially) faster ways of doing this? Are there any safer ways of doing this? Are there any 3rd party tools that I can run against the code base (similar a profiler, maybe?) that can tell me which controls should be removed?

Thanks

Comment: No need of separate project. Do it in the same project with the Help of **Visual Studio , ReSharper & CTRL+SHIFT+B**

Comment: Beware of removing panels and splitters, as  they may be controlling layout, even if they are never directly interacted with.

Comment: Laggy performance is likely not due to extra controls, especially if it builds over time. THat sounds more like a leak of some kind

Comment: The "Document Outline" view (Ctrl+Alt+T) can be helpful if used in conjunction with the designer view as you can select controls and see them selected on the designer. It shows you every single control in a tree hierarchy whether "hidden" or not. It's also handy for altering the Z-order of controls for the rare cases where it's important.

Comment: @Tergiver Thanks for the Document Outline tip off (although, I've been using Visual Studio since '06, I've still not used most of the functions)

Comment: Use a profiler to see what the UI thread is busy doing to make your form laggy.

Comment: @JasonCoyne, I didn't think of that. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

@its bad pracs. to keep unused control in project ..

as technical view it generate problem while page loading / master page loading ...
it show you exception...

Note : Never keep commented code in masterpage ... if server don't under stand that published code.. it show you page but we can't execute it

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't want to remove all controls that are not coded against. Then you will be removing panels and labels that contribute to the UI but never got referenced from outside the designer.

I see two separate concerns here.

One is you have a 'laggy' form. For this just run a profiler and perhaps a memory profiler to find the source of this problem. Then fix that problem. Job done, user happy.

The other is that if there are extra controls that do not contribute to the user experience in any way, for example they are always hidden. This causes the user no problems, but means it can be harder to maintain your code with more controls to wade through. I suggest manually go through and identify these and remove them. Any automated tool would get it wrong.

The first concern is probably a higher priority.